# Django Application, Django forms

Tags: django, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am creating an image classifier application. I am new to Django and what I am trying to do is I take an input image from the user via Django form and running the backend code for classification. After successful submission of the form, I redirect to the same form's page. Again, if I input another/same image, tensorflow throws error. Only when I input image for the first time, error does not occur. Please help!

```
def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})



def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    #image_bytes = f.read()
    #image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
    #image1 = image.resize((224,224))
    #dosom(image1)
    print(f.name)
    dosom(f)
```

The dosom function takes the input image and classifies it. The error thrown is-
'Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(3, 3, 3, 64), dtype=float32)'

Comment: Hello, Welcome to stackoverlfow, Please show your proof of work, where the code crashed and what you are trying to achieve with a sample image.

Comment: Please provide your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a link for the solution to the problem.
https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/issues/80

```
from keras import backend as K
```

and after you've predicted the result, clear the tensorflow session as

```
K.clear_session()
```